# How to observe stdout in TeamCity

Tags: logging, teamcity

This is my third day with TeamCity.

My build steps are:

`Configure: mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..`

`Build: cd build; make -j`

`Run: cd build; ./mybinary`

This fails and I want to know why but no amount of logging to `std::cout` or `std::cerr` shows up in the build logs. What now?